# Without moderators are the lunatics taking over the writing asylum?

Tags: discussion

From my observations it appears the writing section of StackExchange has more people auditioning for a position as moderator than it has productive members. A  small group containing the same names seem to object to every other question and vote to put in hold.

Their very narrow scope of what is 'on topic' virtually negates every question. Either the question is declared 'off topic' or is declared a duplicate question.

New users face the proverbial bureaucratic nightmare. (i) You filled in the wrong form. (ii) You filled in the right form but your in the wrong department. (iii) You filled in the form but you used the wrong colour ink.

The members at issue answer very questions they see as their job to filter questions according to their own judgement.

Oh, wait. I need to as a question.

Based on my observations could I write a story about these issues?

Comment: Yeah... Well... SE now sucks : (

Comment: I'm voting to close this question here, but I do suggest to migrate it to Meta, which is where IMO it belongs.

Comment: @Surtsey If you want to try and turn this into a constructive question, you could provide examples of questions you feel were closed incorrectly, and ask why those types of questions are off-topic or why you believe they aren't duplicates. As for your remark about it being "the same people" closing questions; there really are only a handful of active users here, and it's been that way ever since I can remember. Of *course* you're going to see the same people VTCing every time; they're the only ones who can do so, especially now we don't have moderators to hammer things shut.

Comment: @F1Krazy I imagine that the lunatic refers to that Krazy in your username... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, but: no.

I manually checked the last ten closed questions and did not see any particular evidence that supports the claim.

For reproducibility of the analysis, you have to take into account these facts:

- I assumed that after promotion from Beta, only users with rep > 500 can VTC ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question), [2](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges))
- Only users that have asked or answered a question on the main site in the last three weeks can still be considered "active"

Comment: Only the beta label was removed, reputation requirements for [privileges](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) are still the same. See also the [official announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/352819), which states: "The sites that qualify will: - have the "Beta" removed from their banner [...] -retain beta reputation levels"

Comment: redid the manual counting, still same answer.